# Created Entity using plugin has no valid Entity.Id Value

Tags: entity, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have managed to execute the statement to create an entity successfully without any errors, but the `id` of the entity remains as default `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. In CRM, the created entity did not appear too.

I have not included all fields in the entity, and only inputting 1 field for testing.

Is it due to some mandatory fields not being filled, that is causing the above false positive that the entity is created?

Below is my code snippet:

Call CreateCase(row)

```
foreach (DataRow row in caseTable.Rows)
{
    Entity caseEntity = helper.GetCasebyID((string)row[Excel.ID]);

    if (caseEntity == null)
    {
        caseEntity = CreateCase(row);
    }
}
```

---

CreateCase(row):

```
private Entity CreateCase(DataRow row)
{
    Entity caseEntity = new Entity("new_case");

    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[Excel.sourcename].ToString().Trim())))
    {
        caseEntity.Attributes[Case.sourcename] = row[Excel.sourcename];
    }
    helper.GetOrganizationService().Create(caseEntity);
    Logger.Info(caseEntity.LogicalName + " " + caseEntity.Id + " created. ");
    //output: case 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 created. 
}
```

---

Helper class:

```
public class Helper
{
    private OrganizationServiceProxy _proxy;
    private IOrganizationService _org;

    public IOrganizationService GetOrganizationService()
    {
        if (_org == null)
        {
            var credential = new ClientCredentials();
            credential.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
            credential.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
            credential.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
            Uri organizationUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganizationUri"]);
            Uri homeRealmUri = null;
            _proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credential, null);
            _proxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
            _org = new OrganizationService(_proxy);
        }
        return _org;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the same object to check if record created or guid is available.
Below line in your code return Guid datatype and not subset of object.

```
helper.GetOrganizationService().Create(caseEntity);
```

Also when you create a record, Try to add atleast Primary name attribute value.
In your case it shall be `new_name`

So you should have your code as

```
Guid newlyCreatedCaseRecord = helper.GetOrganizationService().Create(caseEntity);
 Logger.Info(caseEntity.LogicalName + " " + newlyCreatedCaseRecord  + " created. ");
```

You could also fetch newly created Record from Database as Entity object.

```
    Guid newlyCreatedCaseRecord = helper.GetOrganizationService().Create(caseEntity);
        Entity newlyCaseEntity = helper.GetOrganizationService().Retrieve("new_case",newlyCreatedCaseRecord , new ColumnSet(true));
Logger.Info(newlyCaseEntity .LogicalName + " " + newlyCaseEntity.Id + " created. ");
```

Note: There can be Typo in code, try validating in Visual studio.